# How can Angular bootstrap datepicker display "MM/dd/yyyy" and "MM/dd/yy"?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an issue regarding format when I use  Angular bootstrap datepicker.
I want it to display the same value as when I typed.
For example:

- I input "01/01/21", the result I get is 01/01/21
- I input "01/01/2021", the result I get is 01/01/2021

Currently when I enter "01/01/21" or "01/01/2021", the only result is displayed as 01/01/2021.

Here my source code:

```
function directive() {
        return {
            template: '<section class="app-input" ng-show="show">' +
                '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="small-12 columns">' +
                '<div class="label-wrapper " ng-show="label">' +
                '<label >{{label}} <span class="hint">{{hint}}</span>' +
                '<span class="pull-right" ng-show="isRequired()"> (*) </span>' +
                '</label>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="input-wrapper ">' +
                '<p ng-mouseenter="hideTooltip()" class="input-group">' +
                '<input ng-blur="checkDate()" type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="ngModel"' +
                'is-open="popup2.opened" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" data-ng-change="onChange()" datepicker-options="dateOptions"' +
                'ng-required="isRequired()" close-text="Close"/>' +
                '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()">' +
                '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>' +
                '</button>' +
                '</span>' +
                '<a ng-show="showToolTip" style="color:red" uib-tooltip=" Warnning!"> The date your entered not correct ! </a>' +
                '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</section>',
            restrict: 'EAC',
            require: '?ngModel',
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            link: postLink,
            scope: {
                label: "=",
                ngModel: "=",
                type: "=",
                placeholder: "=",
                hint: "=",
                bottomhint: "=",
                readonly: "=",
                name: "=",
                setDefault: "=",
                changeEvent: "<",
                disabled: "="
            },
        };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should use another toggle to select and change format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uib-datepicker receives the format to process as date into the *uib-datepicker-popup* attribute.

In this case you could interpolate this with a variable as in

```
uib-datepicker-popup="{{vm.dateFormat}}"
```

Check the source of your component for the *placeholder* attribute that's also a fixed string. If you want to send the placeholder from the parent component to your directive it should reference a controller variable.

You can check format syntax below

Link reference:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker